Map custom string Id instead of _id in Mongoose Query Population
I have to work on an already developed backend where I need to add a few endpoints. In the user model, they have used userId a custom-generated ID (Cannot change now), but for my API, I want to user populate data with my return response, since the system uses userId instead of _id, I can't map the populate correctly. So how do I populate data?
User Model
export const userSchema: Schema<User> = new Schema<User>({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },

});

const UserModel = mongoose.model<User>("User", userSchema);
export default UserModel;

My Report Model
// Schema for the Report model
const reportSchema: Schema<IReport> = new Schema({
  reportedUserId: { type: String, ref: "User" },
  reporterId: { type: String, required: true, ref: "User" },
  reason: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

export const Report = mongoose.model<IReport>("Report", reportSchema);

Get Report Query
const reports = await Report.find(query)
    .populate({
          path: "reportedUserId",
          select: "userId email name nickname",
          model: UserModel,
          options: { localField: "reportedUserId", foreignField: "userId" },
        })
      
    .skip((page - 1) * limit)
    .limit(limit);
return reports;

Error
Error fetching reports: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "92e15ec7-f34d-4bd3-9b9e-95ba3fa99999" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
    at SchemaObjectId.cast (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectId.js:250:11)
    at SchemaType.applySetters (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1221:12)
    at SchemaType.castForQuery (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1636:17)
    at XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1597:18
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaObjectId.handle$in (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1593:14)
    at SchemaType.castForQuery (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1632:20)
    at cast (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:352:39)
    at Query.cast (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4778:12)
    at Query._castConditions (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2199:10)
    at model.Query._find (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2225:8)
    at model.Query.exec (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4322:80)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  stringValue: '"92e15ec7-f34d-4bd3-9b9e-95ba3fa99999"',
  messageFormat: undefined,
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '92e15ec7-f34d-4bd3-9b9e-95ba3fa99999',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONError: input must be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte Uint8Array, or an integer
      at new ObjectId (XXX\node_modules\bson\lib\bson.cjs:2251:23)
      at castObjectId (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at SchemaObjectId.cast (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectId.js:248:12)
      at SchemaType.applySetters (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1221:12)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1636:17)
      at XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1597:18
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at SchemaObjectId.handle$in (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1593:14)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1632:20)
      at cast (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:352:39)
      at Query.cast (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4778:12)
      at Query._castConditions (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2199:10)
      at model.Query._find (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2225:8)
      at model.Query.exec (XXX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4322:80)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5),
  valueType: 'string',
  model: Model { User }
}

I tried setting the type of reportedUserId and reporterId to the mongoose.Types.ObjectId and use _id, then data populating without an issue, but I cannot change the User table now or frontend data passing auth token logics.

I defined virtual field for reportedUser and values get populated as expected
reportSchema.virtual("reportedUser", {
  ref: UserModel,
  localField: "reportedUserId",
  foreignField: "userId",
  justOne: true,
});

const reports = await Report.find(query)
    .populate({
          path: "reportedUser",
          select: "userId email name nickname",
        })
    .skip((page - 1) * limit)
    .limit(limit);
return reports;


It is throwing a cast error as this :
Error fetching reports: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "92e15ec7-f34d-4bd3-9b9e-95ba3fa99999" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"

It means that the string value "92e15ec7-f34d-4bd3-9b9e-95ba3fa99999" which is the userId stored in Report collection is failed to cast to the type ObjectId.
One of the possible solutions to this issue is to add two new keys in Report collection as shown below. Please also note the changes in definitions of the keys reportedUserId and reporterId, the ref has been removed.
Report Schema changes :
…
{ reportedUserId: { type: String }, 
  reportedUser_id : { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  reporterId: { type: String, required: true },
  reporter_Id: { type: ObjectId, required: true, ref: "User" }, 
…

While retrieval, populate the new keys instead, example below:
const reports = await Report.find({ reportedUserId: userId }).populate(
      'reportedUser_id'
    );

Another solution without schema change would be like this:
set with the value of the key _id instead of userId from User model, example below.
new Report({
reportedUserId: reporteduser._id
reporterId: reporteduser._id
reason: ‘some reason’
})

While retrieval, populate in the normal way:
const reports = await Report.find({ reportedUserId: userId }).populate(
      'reportedUserid'
    );

